# Get Url parameter in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC 5 application I want to use some AngularJS. Now, I have a project card. You can call this card by following the url:

```
http://localhost/Project/Card/1
```

For this card, I have a list of projectTasks. Based on the id = 1 parameter I want AngularJS to show this list, but I don't know how to get the id parameter. I was looking at ngRoute, but I don't want to route I only want to construct a dynamic url in my ProjectTaskController.

What I have so far:

projectApp.js

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module("projectApp", ["ngRoute"]
        .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
             //configure the routing rules here
            $routeProvider.when('/Card/:id', {
                controller: 'ProjectTaskCtrl'
            });

            // enable HTML5mode to disable hashbang urls
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        })
 }());
```

ProjectTask.js

```
(function (app) {
    var projectTaskCtrl = function ($scope, $routeParams) {

    alert($routeParams.id); // message: undefined
};

app.controller("ProjectTaskCtrl", projectTaskCtrl);
}(angular.module("projectApp")));
```

Comment: localhost exists only in your computer.

Comment: @OffirPe'er I know. It is just an example of the url. I don't understand why you devote the question.

Comment: this would work, if your route was `/Show/1`;  is your code showing the wrong route segment, or is your sample URL showing the wrong route?  It's hard to troubleshoot problems with code when the code and the sample don't match.

Comment: @Claies it should be /Card/1. But I still don't get `$routeParams.id = 1` But maybe I'm looking in the wrong direction. I don't need to route. I just want to get parameter from the url and use it.

Comment: that route still doesn't match;  one is `localhost/Project/Card/1` the other is `localhost/Card/1`.  Are you *sure* that you are triggering the right route?

Comment: you haven't shown enough other code here to explain what is going on, but you keep saying you don't want to route.  how else would you have a single page application that responds to multiple URL paths?

Comment: @Claies It could be that I'm looking in the wrong direction, but when you enter the url: http://localhost/Project/Card/1 ASP.NET MVC5 will render a page. On that page, I want to create a small section "Project Tasks". My thought was to render that section with AngularJS. So, when the page loads, it grabs the id from the URL and renders the "Project Tasks" section with AngularJS.

Comment: right, so angular isn't interpreting that `/1`, MVC is?  If you add ng-route, then clicking on links that matched from within your angular app would never make it back to the server.  if your angular app is only on that page, then why can't mvc just pass the data angular needs when it renders the page?

Comment: besides, as I already expressed, the route you posted for angular would only be triggered on `localhost/Card/1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved it by using ng-init:

in my MVC5 View (Show.cshtml) I added:

```
<div id="projectTasks" ng-app="ProjectApp">
    <div ng-controller="ProjectTaskCtrl">
        <input type="hidden" id="projectId" ng-model="projectId" ng-init="projectId=@ViewBag.projectId"/>
        <!-- some more code -->
    </div>
</div>
```

In my ProjectTaskCtrl.js:

```
(function (app) {
    var projectTaskCtrl = function ($scope) {

    $scope.$watch("projectId", function(){
        // I can now use projectId in whatever I want:
        alert($scope.projectId);
    });
};

app.controller("ProjectTaskCtrl", projectTaskCtrl);
}(angular.module("projectApp")));
```